# Interview for job that uses skills you have no experience with?

Tags: c#, php, javascript, css

I am currently employed as a software developer using C# and C++. However, I want to find a new job for personal reasons and applied for a job ad that listed PHP, CSS, and Javascript as the skills the company is looking for. I am interested in learning about PHP, CSS, Javascript. That company wants to interview me. However, I have very little experience with those so I don't know how to prepare. Is it likely that I won't even be asked questions about PHP, CSS, Javascript? What kinds of technical questions do you guys think I will be asked? To succeed, I just need to demonstrate that I am really eager to learn PHP, CSS, Javascript?

Comment: guess why the interviews are made...

Comment: Your obviously just worried about this ... Presumably your current situation is reflected on your CV and they still gave you a interview - that's a good sign. Just go for it!

Comment: I didn't get the job. They flat-out told me during the interview that because I have no experience with PHP,CSS,Javascript, that I wasn't who they were looking for. I never listed experience with those on my resume, so I don't know why they thought I knew those languages well..

Answer (score 3):

My answer looks at the broader aspects of your question - namely, how do you apply for a job where your current programming languages don't match what's required.

1. Be honest with the prospective employer and let them know what your skill level is in those languages which can range from nothing to hobbyist to professional experience.
2. You need to demonstrate how your skills in other languages would carry over to the new languages.
3. You need to start studying up on the new languages *now* and as far in advance of your potential interview.  Don't expect your future employer to train you at their expense.  There are many resources available to help with this.

As far as specific questions or if you have a chance at this interview, I don't know and the community here doesn't know.  A lot of that will come down to the particular job and how much preparation you put in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would I demonstrate my skills in C#/C++ carries over to PHP, CSS, Javascript?

Comment: @user103453 - that would be for you to figure out.  At a minimum, that demonstrates you understand the basics of those languages and the similarities to what you have already done.